# Can we route video on my redundant link while the primary is up and turn it off if the primary fails over to secondary?

Tags: cisco, routing, redundancy, ios

We have a remote location that is currently routing data over a satellite connection.

I am adding a cellular fail over if the satellite goes down.

I have been asked to install video cameras that will stream video, but this takes a lot of bandwidth and satellite is limited to 128k upload.

Is it possible to setup a Cisco router in the following configuration:

- If satellite and cellular are both up - route data over satellite and
  video over cellular.
- If satellite is up and cellular is down - only
  route data over satellite
- If satellite is down and cellular is up -
  only route data over cellular

Is there another solution? We can never lose data, but video is luxury.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look into [IP SLA](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/technologies/tk648/tk362/tk920/technologies_white_paper09186a00802d5efe_ps6602_Products_White_Paper.html) and [policy based routing](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/ps6599/products_white_paper09186a00800a4409.shtml). You should be able to do what you want with a combination of those.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be tempted in your case to set QOS up and give the data priority over video (granted this is backwards of what most of us would do with it).  This would allow the data to take precedence over the video streaming.  And since they are video cameras a few moments of slow frame rates is probably acceptable.  If you are relying on the camera video, local storage on site might be better and stream it from whatever appliance you might use.

A dual wan router can probably accomplish most of this along with QOS.